# Match specific part between curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following example string.

> Hello {{**bob**.name}} bob.name {{john.name}}

I have highlighted the part I'd like to match.
It has to be between two curly brackets in each end and it has to be the first word before the dot.

I have tried this regex `[^{{}}]+(?=\}})` but it matches everything between the curly brackets like this

> Hello {{**bob.name**}} bob.name {{**john.name**}}

It would also be very nice if I could provide a variable for which name to look for.

Comment: Why should it not mach `john`?

Comment: I only want to match a certain name, in my example it is bob and another time it could be john or some other name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with a negated character class, a lookahead and a captured group:

```
/{{([^}.]+)(?=(?:(?!}}).)*}})/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U4nfpD/1)

- `([^}.]+)`: `[^}.]+` matches a character that is not a dot and not a `}`. `(...)` captures in group #1.
- `(?=(?:(?!}}).)*}})` is a lookahead that asserts we have a `}}` ahead.

---

To replace `bob` that is inside `{{...}}` use:

```
repl = str.replace(/({{)bob(?=(?:(?!}}).)*}})/gi, '$1newVal');
```

To match `bob` inside `{{...}}` use:

```
{{bob(?=(?:(?!}}).)*}})
```

Comment: It seems to me it returns {{bob and {{john. I'm also unsure how I could provide a variable to which name to look for, It would be really nice if I could provide a variable with the value bob and it would match {{**bob**.name}} and I could replace the name with something else so it would become {{**newPerson**.name}}

Comment: So your comment below question says you are only looking for a specific name. If that's the case `{{(bob)(?=(?:(?!}}).)*}})` will be your regex

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I have a last question. Your regex matches it as {{bob but I can see the name bob in something called a group. I have tried using replace but it replaces the {{bob part. Do you know how I can replace the "bob" group with a new name?

Comment: You can do: `repl = str.replace(/({{)bob(?=(?:(?!}}).)*}})/gi, '$1newVal');`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`{{([^.]*)[^}]*}}`](https://regex101.com/r/pewEie/1) without any lookahead.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pewEie/1).

`{{ }}` ensures you are inside double brackets.

`([^.]*)` captures every character except a dot.

`[^}]*` matches the rest of what's inside your double brackets.

The first returning group is what you want.

Comment: This will not match if input is `{{bob.n{a}me}}`

Comment: @anubhava Which would be a syntax error more than anything, from my point of view.

Comment: Input is a text, wrapped in `{{...}}` there is no other syntax as per OP

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?<={{)([^{}]+?)(?=(?:\.(.*))?}})
```

It matches only *bob* and have 2 matchied groups: first - *bob* and second - *name*.

You can use it like this (used ES6 syntax):

```
const str = 'Hello {{bob.name}} bob.name {{john.name}}';
str.replace(/(?<={{)([^{}]+?)(?=(?:\.(.*))?}})/g, (allMatch, person, property) => {
  console.log(`All match = ${allMatch}, person = ${person}, property = ${property}`);
}));
```